# How can I stop users to stop bypassing load balancer

Tags: iis, load-balancing, hosts

We have issue with asp application where we have application deployed on 3 servers
Server1
Server2
Server3

Application should be accessed by URL `http://app1.us.testdomain/testapp/`
 Currently we have users who are by passing load balancer url and access application directly on individual server like
`http://Server1/testapp/default.asp`
`http://Server2/testapp/default.asp`
Causing inconsistent distribution of load across the servers.

Is it possible to prevent this for users at IIS or load balancer level.